# Change colour for dynamic element on click

Tags: angular

How do you change [color] of a element when user clicks on it.
Using Angular 12, and Angular Material.

HTML

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemList">
   <button mat-raised-button (click)="viewItem(item)" [color]="'default'">{{item.name}}</button>
</ng-container>
```

TS

```
viewItem(item: any) {
    console.log(item.name + " has been clicked");
}
```

I want to change the button [color] to 'primary',
There can be 1 or N number of items (dynamic list).

Answer (score 1):

You can update the structure of your list to include a new property called as color and then dynamically bind that to the HTML. Example:

```js
itemList = [
  { name: 'ABC', color: 'primary' },
  { name: 'PQR', color: 'secondary' },
  { name: 'XYZ', color: 'default' }
];
```

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of itemList">
   <button mat-raised-button (click)="viewItem(item)" [color]="item.color">{{item.name}}</button>
</ng-container>
```